# Firebase Cloud Functions upgrading downtime

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm developing a medium sized app, which is going to have quite a few customers.

Thing is, we're most likely going to add or upgrade current functions, after launch, so, given some functions are dealing with the user's wallets based on their transactions, I'm wondering what happens if I am to upgrade a function like that.

Would some of the database triggers fail to run due to the function being updated ? Would the function defer / re-queue those triggers ? Is there any guarantee Cloud Functions will get triggered for each and every single event ?

I did not find anything regarding that being stated in the documentation nor their (your -- for any Firebase members out here) site.

Real use-case:
1. A function is defined to trigger onCreate under a node filled with transactions and subtract each transaction's amount from the related user's wallet.
2. A transaction is created by the user
3. Function's triggered, his funds are credited / debited based on the transaction's amount.

Job done! Or, is it ?

Comment: You've got too many questions here for a single post.  Please limit yourself to one question at a time.  That way it can receive an answer from anyone who knows, separately from the other questions that they may not know.  You are also asking for offsite resources, which is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's actually only one question Doug. The rest of it are use-cases so readers understand what I'm trying to do. Is there any downtime for upgrading a cloud function, and if there is, how can I see it.

Comment: "Is there any tool to monitor any failed hits ? Please advise if you have any knowledge on the matter."

Comment: Yes. I would guess, that, if there is any downtime, there should be a way to be aware of it, right ? And so far I haven't seen anything inside firebase dash. Hence, the question. It's all the same thing, no matter how you want to read it.

But, just because you really want to close my question, I'll edit and remove that bit, hopefully then it becomes painly obvious for readers.

Comment: Or, maybe it's just something that you don't like people seeing or asking, hence the close vote. In which case, ( if it's true ) that's a shame, because I've always been a paying customer for Google products.

Comment: Stack Overflow has its own rules.  This has nothing to do with Google.

Comment: I've cleaned up my question, hope you're happy now, care to answer ?

Comment: This question is a bit vague - and I am not really sure what you're asking. A function will continue to operate as long as the parameters set in the function remain consistent. So if for example, a cloud function examines a /users node. If you then 'update' the cloud function to examine the /cool_users node, it will obviously break. Again, that's stating the obvious. What would lead you to think that a function would suddenly stop working? In other words whether you create a new function or update an existing one, they function as long as they are coded correctly - what would make them stop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redeploying a function should not cause it to miss any events.

If you want to know what execution guarantees you get, you should [consult the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#execution_guarantees) about that.

> Background functions are invoked at least once. This is because of the
>   asynchronous nature of handling events, in which there is no caller
>   that waits for the response. The system might, in rare circumstances,
>   invoke a background function more than once in order to ensure
>   delivery of the event. If a background function invocation fails with
>   an error, it will not be invoked again unless retries on failure are
>   enabled for that function.

Comment: I've consulted the docs, but it was Firebase's docs, not Google Clouds' so there was nothing mentioned about that. Thanks for the link.

Comment: They are the same product. Firebase just adds extra tools and SDKs.